# ¿de que forma puedo leer un archivo .csv en c#? estoy usando una libreria csv helper

Tags: c#, csv, visual, studio

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using CsvHelper;
    using System.Globalization;


namespace Ejercicio6_CSV
{
    public class Program
    {
       
            static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Alumno> a = new List<Alumno>();

            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("1: Cargar Alumnos desde CSV----");
            Console.WriteLine("2: Cargar Alumnos desde XML");
            Console.WriteLine("3: Cargar alumnos desde JSON");
            Console.WriteLine("4: Listar Alumnos");
            Console.WriteLine("5: Buscar Alumno");
            Console.WriteLine("6: Terminar");

            StreamReader arch = new StreamReader(@"alumnos.csv");
            CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(arch,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            //  parser.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";

          

        }
    }
}
```

De que forma podria leer un archivo.csv ?, como podria solucionarlo o implementarlo a mi codigo? me complico un poco el ejercicio.
Tengo mi clase Alumno con atributos,y tambien un tabla con alumnos.csv, quiero cargar esa tabla, pero no se de que forma puede ser.

Comment: ¿Qué forma tiene tu .csv? Por lo que veo estás usando una librería externa, considera mencionarlo en tu pregunta.

Comment: m... estoy usando una 5x34, cada columna separadas por comas, donde hay id,rut,nombre,completo,email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo la clase que define tu entidad, por ejemplo:

```
class Alumno
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}, {Name}";
    }
}
```

y el siguiente `csv`:

```
Id,Name
1,Alberto
2,Tatiana
```

La lectura del `csv`, según la [documentación oficial](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file), se puede realizar de manera sencilla usando:

```
List<Alumno> students;

using (var reader = new StreamReader("/path/students.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    students = csv.GetRecords<Alumno>().ToList();
}
```

Nota que la cabecera de tu archivo debe matchear **de manera exacta** con las propiedades de tu clase, de lo contrario vas a obtener una excepción.

He probado el programa que te acabo de adjuntar imprimiendo los alumnos del archivo con el siguiente ciclo y funciona perfectamente.

```
foreach (var student in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student);
}
```

Comment: var records = csv.GetRecords<Alumno>().ToList(); me genera error aca que es CsvHelper.ReaderException: 'No members are mapped for type 'Ejercicio6_CSV.Alumno'.

Comment: ¿Estás usando propiedades en tu clase `Alumno`?

Comment: igual en using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\crist\\Desktop\\alumnos.csv"))     le agregue eso por donde esta ubicado mi alumnos.csv

Comment: ¿Cual es la excepción en la línea de `var reader`?

Comment: solamente uso metodos get y to string

Comment: ¿solo métodos `get`? ¿Cómo esperas que se les dé valor a las propiedades si no tienes `set`?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135327/discussion-between-jaime-menendez-and-cristian-guerrero-nenen).

Comment: gracias amigo!!!! te pasaste:))))9